# locking images in Excel without un-checking Edit Objects

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document and I need to lock the images in position.
I know un-checking Edit Objects can do this, but, the problem I have is that I also have a command button on the same sheet, which allows the user to browse to a file, so I need Edit Objects ticked (checked) as un-checking stops the button from working.
I've tried editing the image properties, but nothing I've tried thus far seems to work, any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

With objects it's all or nothing. You can't set Edit Object per object.

But you don't need to.

If you insert a shape, assign a macro to the shape, then protect the sheet, leaving "Edit Objects" **unchecked**, then the shape can still be clicked and will fire the macro. You don't need to edit the button in order to fire the macro.

The screenshot shows that the sheet is protected, and the macro still runs when the shape is clicked.

[image]